# Can you help me use tikz to draw this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a figure but it is well beyond my skill set (I only used a little bit of `tikz` in the past and that was a long time ago). The figure I need is this one:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would love to provide a MWE but the problem is (quite literally) that I do not know where to start. Beyond pointing me to `tikz`'s CTAN documentation, would anyone please help me get started with the figure I need?

You can ignore the dark background with thin white lines, and since it will likely be printed, you can also make sure that different color lines follow different patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your difficulties are scaling the whole figure and scaling texts: see `[scale=.2]` and `[scale=1.5]` inside a `node`. Other things are just basic: `rectangle`, `circle`, `opacity`, `grid`, `line width`, `rounded corners`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\pagecolor{black!65}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2,rounded corners=2pt]
\draw[white,very thin,opacity=.05] (0,0) grid (32,25); 
\begin{scope}[line width=2.2pt]
\draw[white] (1,1) rectangle (31,24) (1,1) node[above right,scale=1.5] {$v$}; 
\draw[red] (2,5) rectangle (26,23) (2,23) node[below right,scale=1.3] {$v_m$}; 
\draw[green] (8,2) rectangle (30,20) (30,2) node[above left,scale=1.2] {$v_c$}; 
\draw[yellow] (9,6) rectangle +(13,6) (9,6) node[above right] {$v_f$}; 
\draw[blue] (9,13) rectangle +(12,6) (9,13) node[above right] {$v_k$}; 
\draw[magenta] (12,7) rectangle +(8,4) (12,7) +(1,1) node[scale=.8] {$v_0$}; 
\draw[orange] (14,8) rectangle +(3,2) node[midway,scale=.8] {$v_d$}; 
\fill[pink] (18,9) circle(.25) +(1,0 )node[scale=.8] {$v_u$}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the bare minimum knowledge to draw this, basically all you need to know how to do is draw thick lines of different colors (for example `line width=5pt`), know how to make rectangles, and know how to use nodes to put text at specific points. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tutorials) has some pretty good tutorials, for example [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package#Introduction).

Comment: Thank you! I knew Overleaf has several tutorials, but failed to spot that one.